# Как скрыть курсор в EditText

Tags: java, android

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии `Activity` в поле `EditText` не было курсора (поле становится активным по умолчанию), но он должен появится при нажатии пользователем на это `EditText`.

И какое событие отвечает за потерю фокуса, чтобы при нажатии за пределами `EditText` я убирал курсор с `EditText` и скрывал клавиатуру?

Comment: В одном вопросе рекомендуется решать не более одной проблемы. Для идей *"А как мне сделать еще и это .."* задавайте новый вопрос. Это не ваши персональные консультации, а база знаний и решений конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Ведь есть метод для изменения видимости курсора.

```
editText.setCursorVisible();
```

Comment: Спасибо, а какое событие отвечает за потерю фокуса (чтобы при нажатии на пустое место Activity я убирал курсор с EditText и скрывал клавиатуру)?

Comment: чтобы при нажатии за пределами EditText я убирал курсор с EditText и скрывал клавиатуру

Comment: @VladLynnik,  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Метод imm.isActive() вернёт состояние клавиатуры. А метод setFocusable вашего EditText уберёт фокус с него.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Возможно здесь вы найдёте больше информации.

Comment: Скрывать клавиатуру, тапая по экрану, вы можете прослушивая события MotionEvent.

Comment: Можно пример?!?